# Create simple and secure transaction without checksig?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, script

According to my previously asked question ([P2SH secure spending. How?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/82967/p2sh-secure-spending-how/82983#82983)) creating transactions without signature checking is probably not secure.

Anyway, I see many transactions

`(for ex.:40eee3ae1760e3a8532263678cdf64569e6ad06abc133af64f735e52562bccc8)`

with scriptpubkey like:
OP_HASH160 [pubkey] OP_EQUAL

With very similar to

```
OP_SHA256 [hash] OP_EQUAL (from my prev. question)
```

And scriptsig doesnt have OP_CHECKSIG

```
PUSHDATA(72)[3045022100ad0851c69dd756b45190b5a8e97cb4ac3c2b0fa2f2aae23aed6ca97ab33bf88302200b248593abc1259512793e7dea61036c601775ebb23640a0120b0dba2c34b79001] 

PUSHDATA(69)[5141042f90074d7a5bf30c72cf3a8dfd1381bdbd30407010e878f3a11269d5f74a58788505cdca22ea6eab7cfb40dc0e07aba200424ab0d79122a653ad0c7ec9896bdf51ae]
```

I can't beleeve this transaction are insecure. But what the difference with this ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This transaction actually does have a signature check. Instead of OP_CHECKSIG, it's OP_CHECMULTISIG as the script is a multisignature script. The script in this case is the redeemScript which is provided in the input itself. To see this OP_CHECKMULSITIG, you need to decode the redeemScript.

The redeemScript is:

```
5141042f90074d7a5bf30c72cf3a8dfd1381bdbd30407010e878f3a11269d5f74a58788505cdca22ea6eab7cfb40dc0e07aba200424ab0d79122a653ad0c7ec9896bdf51ae
```

Decoded, this redeemScript is:

```
1 042f90074d7a5bf30c72cf3a8dfd1381bdbd30407010e878f3a11269d5f74a58788505cdca22ea6eab7cfb40dc0e07aba200424ab0d79122a653ad0c7ec9896bdf 1 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

As you can see, this has an OP_CHECKMULTISIG in it which does do a signature check. OP_CHECKMULTISIG checks that `n` of the public keys listed provide a signature. `n` is the number that is at the beginning of the script. In this case, `n` is 1, and the public key is `042f90074d7a5bf30c72cf3a8dfd1381bdbd30407010e878f3a11269d5f74a58788505cdca22ea6eab7cfb40dc0e07aba200424ab0d79122a653ad0c7ec9896bdf`. So this script is looking for a signature that corresponds to that public key.

Comment: I'm still don't get it. Ok, in input we can set op_checkmultisigsig and be sure that transaction can't be replaced. It's no requered for spending, right? What if some funds left with the same scriptpubkey (HASH160 [pubkey] EQUAL)? To spend inputs, we just need to provide data, which HASH160 will equal to e9c3dd0c07...e9c3dd0c07. So, we know that data from spending transaction (its 3045022100ad0...a2c34b79001) Where is my mistake?

Comment: The output script is a special type known as P2SH. You have to provide something in the input which hashes to that hash. But, that something itself is also a script and is interpreted too. So you must also meet the conditions of that script too. Since that script includes an OP_CHECKMULTISIG, you will need to provide signatures, and without the private keys, you can't do that.